# Strange behaviour of Transactions Control

Tags: postgresql

I was looking into transaction control in PL/pgSQL from their documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html)

As per the docs it says DO blocks and Procs behave the same so i wrote following code to verify(clone from link example)

```
 DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$QLambda$
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 0..9 LOOP
        INSERT INTO test1 (a) VALUES (i);
        IF i % 2 = 0 THEN
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            ROLLBACK;
        END IF;
 END LOOP;
END
$QLambda$;
```

and it works with like charm until you turn off auto commit of pgAdmin and get following error

```
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at COMMIT
SQL state: 2D000
```

Question:How is auto commit impeding DO block it should already run within its own transaction, or does auto commit force it to become a sub transaction.. i am confused with transaction control in PG proc.. can someone explain with working code..

Comment: Frequent commits don't improve anything. More often than not, that makes things actually slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `psql` with `autocommit` on(the default):

```
create table test1(a int);

DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$QLambda$
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 0..9 LOOP
        INSERT INTO test1 (a) VALUES (i);
        IF i % 2 = 0 THEN
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            ROLLBACK;
        END IF;
 END LOOP;
END
$QLambda$;

select * from test1;
 a 
---
 0
 2
 4
 6
 8
(5 rows)
```

With `autocommit` off, you get, from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> The autocommit-off mode works by issuing an implicit BEGIN for you, just before any command that is not already in a transaction block and is not itself a BEGIN or other transaction-control command, nor a command that cannot be executed inside a transaction block (such as VACUUM).

So to make that explicit:

```
BEGIN;
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$QLambda$
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 0..9 LOOP
        INSERT INTO test1 (a) VALUES (i);
        IF i % 2 = 0 THEN
            COMMIT;
        ELSE
            ROLLBACK;
        END IF;
 END LOOP;
END
$QLambda$;
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at COMMIT
```

So it is the `autocommit` off case that has the nested transaction.

Comment: Thanks, Its was so non intuitive, but what makes me wonder is when auto commit is on and if no one is issuing a commit how is the transaction id changing?

Comment: There is a `commit` done it is just behind the scenes, hence `autocommit`.

Comment: There is still something a miss here or i have not understood it, How do we make autocommit off behave like autocommit on Explicitly in the above example?

Comment: Well in `psql` you can use `\set autocommit on` just before the `DO` to get it to run. The `\set autocommit off` after. Not sure how that would work in pgAdmin?

Comment: Oh not in that way, what i meant is assume autocommit to be set off, now using sql can i explicitly use commits to simulate the same behaviour as when auto commit on?, in simple words Write sql code to provide functionality of auto commit for the above example in a autocommit off enviroment..

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: FYI, with `autocommit` on you can still use explicit `BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK` to wrap transactions manually. Use `BEGIN` in this situation turns off `autocommit` until  you do a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.